# Hosting my Visual Studios Web Form in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

[IIS Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvpf1.png)

[IE Error when browsing to site from IIS interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIs0f.png)

[Files and Folders output from "Publish Web App"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2TwM.png)

[DLL files output by publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKSD0.png)

I have a web form written in Visual Studio. Built in .NET Framework 4. Has been published and added into IIS on Server 2012r2. I am just getting an error saying page can't be found.. there is already a page hosted here and it works fine, but I have no to very little knowledge on how any of it works.. Just following not particularly helpful guides online. I would very much like some input.. Just comment on what particular info you would need and I can add it.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind posting some screenshots? Without knowing where you published the WebForms app on IIS (a site? an application?) and the actual error (what URL in browser? What sub status code in IIS logs?), nobody can really help you any.

Comment: I will get some together. I wrote the code on my computer. Used the publish tool in Visual Studio and copied those files to the web server to host using the IIS application on the server. I will post pictures of the error and of what files I have

Comment: Edited to include screenshots and snips, going through logs now to pull only ones relevant to my project

Comment: Does the domain name `local.blockreport.com` resolves to the IP address in the site binding?

Comment: No. Not yet anyway. I want to make sure that the site can be found by the iis application first. If I cant get into it from there then I am not going to be able to anywhere.

Comment: That's exactly the cause of "Page not found". "I want to make sure that..." is helpless as you are on the wrong track. The terms "site" and "applications" have their unique meanings under IIS context, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis So make sure you describe crystal clearly what you really want to do, so that others can understand.

Comment: OK I dont see how I can be more clear. It is a web form. It is written in Visual Studio 2008. Built and Published from Visual Studio 2010. Same code, same project, just an updated framework. It is published ,like I said, in the IIS application on Server 2012R2 I have described the error on the page. I have made clear that the page cannot be viewed from the browse action in IIS. I would say that's pretty clear. If you really need more information then you will have to tell me what you need. I do not have knowledge in Web Hosting and have made that clear as well.